# Button selection on BOOL UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am attempting to show a button in the selected state when based on a boolean off of JSON. Here is my code for my custom UITableViewCell:

```
TwitterCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TwitterCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TwitterCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TwitterCell"];
    }

    NSDictionary *data = tweets[indexPath.row];

    id favorited = data[@"favorited"];
    NSLog(@"%@",favorited);
    id retweeted = data[@"retweeted"];
    NSLog(@"%@",retweeted);

    if ((int)favorited == 1) {
        [cell.favoriteButton select];
    } else {
        [cell.favoriteButton deselect];
    }

    if ((int)retweeted == 1) {
        [cell.retweetButton select];
    } else {
        [cell.retweetButton deselect];
    }
```

Here is a possible point of issue in my custom TableViewCell class. Where I prepare for reuse:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.favoriteButton.selected = NO;
    self.tweetLabel.text = nil;
    self.profilePicture.image = nil;
    self.nameLabel.text = nil;
    self.retweetButton.selected = NO;
    self.usernameLabel.text = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with the code you have provided.

### 1 - Casting `NSNumber` to `int`

Retrieving `favorited`, which is presumably a number, from the dictionary will return an [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/) which is a wrapper class for numbers. When you `NSLog` this it will print the result of it's `description` method, essentially printing out the underlying number.

When you cast an `NSNumber` to `int` you don't get the underlying number but the memory address in integer format.

See this code and some example output:

```
NSNumber *favorited = @(1);
NSLog(@"%@", favorited);
NSLog(@"%d", (int)favorited);

favorited = @(0);

NSLog(@"%@", favorited);
NSLog(@"%d", (int)favorited);
```

Outputs

```
2015-08-19 07:04:36.235 xctest[589:7545] 1
2015-08-19 07:04:36.236 xctest[589:7545] 18
2015-08-19 07:04:36.236 xctest[589:7545] 0
2015-08-19 07:04:50.720 xctest[589:7545] 2
```

To retrieve the underlying number it is necessary to use one of the appropriate `*value` methods such as [`integerValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumber/integerValue) or [`longValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumber/longValue).

### 2 - Calling `select` and `deselect`

Neither of these methods exist on `UIButton` unless you have created a custom subclass. To properly adjust the selected state of a button you need to use the [`selected`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/selected) property as you have done in the `prepareForReuse` method.

```
button.selected = YES; // or NO
```

### Putting it all together

Taking the above information we can change part of the cell creation method as follows:

```
if ([favorited integerValue] == 1) {
    cell.favoriteButton.selected = YES;
} else {
    cell.favoriteButton.selected = NO;
}

if ([retweeted integerValue] == 1) {
    cell.retweetButton.selected = YES;
} else {
    cell.retweetButton.selected = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with

`(int)favorited == 1`

Just use `[favorited intvalue]` things will be fine.

Comment: (int)favourite is not equal to [favourite intValue]